# Laravel - login in Bootstrap modal

Tags: laravel, authentication, bootstrap-modal

I want to add login and register in my homepage using Bootstrap modal, but when I add form and everything needed for login or register and click Submit or Save changes it doesn't do anything.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">LOGIN</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
                </div>                               
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">REGISTRACIJA</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
            @csrf
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Vas username sa kojim cete se prikazivati na Autoplac zajednici!</small>
                    @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email adresa</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Vasa email adresa sa kojom cete se ulogovati na Autoplac zajednici.</small>
                    @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Vas password ne dijelite ni sa kim!</small>
                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrujte se</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And when I paste just login form, for example, on some other pages it works perfectly! Could it be something with the modal? I can't understand why it can't work here, on my homepage modal. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: When something is failing for no obvious reason, you have to check your assumptions, look for anything odd, and try to reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In this case, there is one glaringly obvious thing that is unusual - you have 2 sets of modal code squished into 1 modal. I have no idea if that matters, but if things aren't working, that seems like the clear first thing to investigate.  Strip out your register modal HTML, so your [modal HTML is standard](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals).

Comment: PS `Save Changes` is pretty strange for a login button!? :-)